# Append a string to the end of an element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will add/remove checkbox values into the array. I want to create the array name from the element's ID attribute (I am not sure if it's the best way to achieve). If ID is "color" values will be pushed to "colorFilter" or if ID is "size" it will be pushed to "sizeFilter". Problem is that I get "filterArray.push is not a function" error.

```
var colorFilter = [];
var sizeFilter = [];

$('.filter').each(function () {
    var filterName = $(this).attr("id");
    var filterArray = filterName + "Filter";
    $(this).find('a').on( 'click', function( event ) {

        var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
        var val = $target.attr( 'data-value' );
        var $input = $target.find( 'input' );
        var idx;

        if ( ( idx = filterArray.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
            filterArray.splice( idx, 1 );
            setTimeout( function() { $input.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
        } else {
            filterArray.push( val );
            setTimeout( function() { $input.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
        }

        getItems();
    });
});
function getItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "#",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            'color': colorFilter,
            'size': sizeFilter
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<ul id="color" class="filter">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="red">
            <input type="checkbox"/>Red
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="blue">
            <input type="checkbox"/>Blue
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="size" class="filter">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="10x14">
            <input type="checkbox"/>10x14
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="3x5">
            <input type="checkbox"/>3x5
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `push` only works on arrays, not strings, and what you've named `filterArray` is just a string

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I actually defined the array.

Comment: in you code you are pusing the values to a non array variable named filterArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a variable with the desired name before accessing it

`window[filterArray] = new Array();` then use this variable instead. 
The way you implemented it `filterArray` is just a string not an array
so your code will be

```
$('.filter').each(function () {
   var filterName = $(this).attr("id");
   var filterArray = filterName + "Filter";
   if(typeof(window[filterArray]) == 'undefined' || window[filterArray] == null)
       window[filterArray] = new Array();
   $(this).find('a').on( 'click', function( event ) {

       var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
       var val = $target.attr( 'data-value' );
       var $input = $target.find( 'input' );
       var idx;

       if ( ( idx = window[filterArray].indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
           window[filterArray].splice( idx, 1 );
           setTimeout( function() { $input.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
       } else {
           window[filterArray].push( val );
           setTimeout( function() { $input.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
       }

   });
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code, when I alert(filterArray) I get the corresponding array name but It doesn't put the values to the array when I console.log(window[filterArray])

Comment: a couple of things, I updated the code to check if the variable exists before add it. Second, where do you use `console.log(window[filterArray])` ?

Comment: you are right it works. I was trying to pass it to another function https://jsfiddle.net/xg4c4d6p/3/

Comment: almost there,`colorFilter`,`sizeFilter` don't exist for two reasons, they are plural `colors` and `sizes` and second you can only access them using `window` global variable check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/thesane/xg4c4d6p/4/

Comment: perfect! thank you so much for spending lots of time for me!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're expecting the filter array name to be `$(this).attr("id") + "Filter"`, and you defined `colorFilter` and `sizeFilter`, but your elements ids are `"colors"` and `"sizes"`, not `"color"` and `"size"`.

Second, instead of `var filterArray = filterName + "Filter";`, you need `var filterArray = window[filterName + "Filter"];`.  This will capture the array that you're looking for.

Finally, move the declarations of filterName and filterArray inside the onclick event handler, like this:

```
$(this).find('a').on( 'click', function( event ) {
    var filterName = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
    var filterArray = window[filterName + "Filter"];
    var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
    var val = $target.attr( 'data-value' );
    var $input = $target.find( 'input' );
    var idx;

    if ( ( idx = filterArray.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
        filterArray.splice( idx, 1 );
        setTimeout( function() { $input.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
    } else {
        filterArray.push( val );
        setTimeout( function() { $input.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
    }

});
```

Comment: you are right, sorry! I updated it. When I define it as you say I get " Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: oh, you're right - I see.  You need to move the declarations of filterName and filterArray inside the onclick event handler.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but stills gives me the same indexof error.